# Compare single value to column of values and find maximum in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a single value that I'm trying to compare with a column and find the max between each row as such:

```
input:
val = 5
df['col1'] = [4,6,2]

expected output:
df['col1'] = [5,6,5]
```

The approach i've taken so far is to try to find the max using the max function:

```
df['col1'] = max(val, df['col1'])

The error I'm getting is as follows: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I'm guessing this is because it's not able to compare one val to many in the column but I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: [`df.clip(lower=5)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a list comprehension:

```
df['col1'] = [max(val,el) for el in df['col1']
```